# How to customize maintenance mode notification in wordpress?

Tags: plugins, customization, notifications, maintenance

I am installing and activating the SeeProd plugin. but it did not work. I need to another simple method to  customize maintenance mode notification.

Answer (score 0):

If you set up your WordPress website on maintenance mode manually before installing any updates, you can avoid displaying the default maintenance mode notification simply.

Furthermore, you can perform the below steps to customize the maintenance mode notification correctly again.

1. Activate the [SeeProd plugin](https://trendyport.com/how-to-fix-briefly-unavailable-for-scheduled-maintenance-error-in-wordpress/).
2. Go to Settings and then go to the Coming Soon Pro page.
3. Enable maintenance mode option checkbox.
4. Click on the Edit Coming Soon/Maintenance Page button.
5. It will open the SeeProd theme customizer.
6. Open the SeeProd theme customizer.
7. Select a theme and customize the theme.
8. Then you can create a beautiful maintenance mode page for the website.

You can create a maintenance page on the site without using a plugin. Then it will not require to set up the website in maintenance mode at every time updated.

9. You can do it simply by creating a new file and referred to as maintenance.php on the desktop.
10. Then you can paste below code inside it.
11. Upload that file to WordPress site’s wp-content directory. Then WordPress will display this created page during maintenance mode. As well as you can use CSS to style the page as your requirement

Comment: Thank you for this details.